Tkinter keyboard based time input
I'm looking for a way to input time to tkinter but all of the examples I can find are either unnecessarily fancy https://pypi.org/project/tkTimePicker/ or just slow to input https://pypi.org/project/tkTimePicker/ I'm writing the GUI as part of a tool for working with logs internally meaning the users will be fairly technical and care far more about the program functioning quickly than looking pretty.
Something like a html time input that you can simply type numbers into while it prevents you from inputting invalid times would be perfect (especially if it comes with an option for dates and/or lets you tab between the boxes. Does something like this exist for tkinter?
In summery I'd like

Time input
Fast to enter
is able to validate time automatically (i.e. you can't put in minute=76)


you'll need to 'roll your own' for this functionality

Writing your own isn’t all that difficult. Have you tried?

tkcalendar. Tk is minimalistic. If you need some custom functionality for widgets, you'll need to write it yourself.
